# What is “Basis of a Group”?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have an assignment, that beside other things, asks about a basis of a group, more precisely, it have been asked to "give an example of a basis for $T_d$" (tetrahedron group).

But I been on all lectures and searched internet for such a definition, but found nothing.

Any idea what "Group Basis" means? maybe it has some other name also?

P.S

There was no mentioning of any kind of group representations in this questions, so I suspect that this is something related to representations.

Comment: It could mean "a set of generators".

Comment: @Arthur, I thought that too, but are you sure?

Comment: Why not ask your teacher for clarification?

Comment: Yes, probably a set of generators is meant. E.g. for $\mathbb{Z}^2$, the generators could be $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, the basis vectors that form a 2D lattice under repeated addition and subtraction. Compare also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group

Comment: Note that the group in question is neither a free group nor a free abelian group. The term "basis" should be used here IMHO. Please ask somebody for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

It means a set of generators, such that every element of the generated group has a unique representation in terms of the generators.

Comment: I do not think uniqueness of representation is required, as this is impossible for groups with torsion.  However, minimality of some sort is a reasonable requirement, i.e., that no proper subset of the generating set still generates.  The size of such a set need not be constant as it is for vector spaces, but I do not think people generally require the minimum number of generators.

Comment: I think in terms of groups "basis" is only related to free groups, and a free group F with basis X(in the sense of the definition in my last answer) has unique represention in X. And free groups are torsion-free, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: The question specifically mentions a non-free group, though, so your assumption is manifestly false.

Answer (score 0):

R. Lyndon and P. Schupp defined in their book "Combinatory Group Theory" a free group F with basis X in the following way:

"Let X be a subset of a group F. Then F is a free group with basis X
provided the following holds: if $\phi$ is any function from the set X into a group H,
then there exists a unique extension of $\phi$ to a homomorphism $\phi^*$ from F into H.
"