# When can an operator $\omega : G \to A$ for a group $G \subset A$ be extended to a map $A \to A$?

Tags: group-theory

First, a word on notation, I define $\vec{v}_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is an ordinal as $\{ v_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \kappa \}$.

I'm going to consider a slight generalization of a group with operators.

Let $G \subset A$ be a group and $\Omega$ be a set of operators and let $\omega$ be an otherwise propertyless element of $\Omega$.

Ordinarily, $\omega$ is a map $G \to G$. Let's consider a slight extension of that and make it a map $G \to A$ satisfying the following rule:

$$ g^\omega h^\omega = (gh)^\omega $$

**I'm wondering whether $\omega$ can always be extended to a map from $A$ to $A$. And, if not, under what circumstances it cannot be extended.**

---

What follows is my attempt to prove this statement myself. However, **this proof is not valid because it makes at least one unjustified assumption**, namely that I can get a [minimal generating set of a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480103/what-is-basis-of-a-group) of a specified cardinality. I'm also not sure whether specifying the definition of an operator on all elements of a minimal generating set and inverses of such elements is sufficient to uniquely define the operator. I'm additionally uncertain about whether a group always has a minimal generating set, since the generating set is required to generate any group element using only finitely many factors.

---

*This is my attempted proof.*

Suppose $G = A$, then we're done because $\omega$ is already a map from $A$ to $A$.

Suppose $G$ is a proper subset of $A$.

Let $\vec{a}_\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is some ordinal be a minimal generating set for $A$. Let $\vec{a}_{\lambda_0}$ where $\lambda_0 \in \lambda$ be a minimal generating set for $G$.

Let $\vec{b}_\lambda$ be a minimal generating set for $A$ that is potentially different from $\vec{a}_\lambda$. Let $\vec{b}_\kappa$ where $\kappa \in \lambda$ be a minimal generating set for $G^\omega$. Let us further impose the constraint that $\kappa \le \lambda_0$.

I define $\xi$, the extension of $\omega$ as follows.

For $a_\mu$ where $\mu \in \lambda_0$, let $(a_\mu)^\xi = (a_\mu)^\omega $. Anything inside $\vec{a}_{\lambda_0}$ gets sent wherever $\omega$ would have sent it normally.

For $(a_\mu)^{-1}$ where $\mu \in \lambda_0$, let $((a_\mu)^{(-1)})^\xi$ be $((a_\mu)^{(-1)})^\omega$.

For $a_\mu$ where $\mu \not\in \lambda_0$, let $(a_\mu)^\xi = b_\mu$. Anything outside $\vec{a}_{\lambda_0}$ gets send to the corresponding element of the minimal generating set $\vec{b}$, $(b_\mu)^{(-1)}$.

For $a_\mu$ where $\mu \not\in \lambda_0$, let $((a_\mu)^{(-1)})^\xi$ be $(b_\mu)^{(-1)}$.

Thus, for any group element $g$ in $A$, $\xi$ is determined. Any group element can be written as a finite product of generators and inverses of generators.

Comment: Your usage of "basis" is, indeed, nonstandard. The common way to refer to a set that generates but no proper subset generates is "minimal generating set".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks, I removed the usage of the word "basis".

Comment: In line 3 of your attempted proof, you seem to assume that a minimal generating set of a subgroup is smaller than a minimal generating set of the whole group. However, for any finite number $k$ there is a 2-generated group with a subgroup that cannot be generated by fewer than $k$ elements.

Comment: Adding to Arturo's comment: it's not only non-standard, it even leads to conflicting nomenclature: all abelian groups are naturally $\mathbb Z$-modules, and their generating sets as groups or modules are the same. But not all such modules have a basis. In fact, only the free abelian groups have one - which agrees with the convention that modules with a basis are called free.

Comment: @JackSchmidt ... Thanks, that's a good point and probably makes the proof attempt unsalvageable. I think based on the linked question that there can be minimal generating sets of the same group of different cardinalities, since minimality is a local property wrt the lattice of subgroups. If I have a group $A$ with a distinguished subgroup $G$, can I pick a minimal generating set for $A$ with a distinguished subset that generates $G$ or does that not work?

Comment: I think the next main problem is that of "relations" (you are working on the generator part, but then the next thing to worry about is relations). In the "when" part, I mentioned the "direct summand" condition. This is very close to your original word, "basis". Not only is it a minimal generating set, but it is now "linearly independent", and so you can define images as you wanted to in your proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, it is not always possible to extend an operator from a subgroup to the full group.

As an example, take $A$ to be dihedral of order 8, and $G$ to be a non-cylic subgroup of order 4. Then $G$ has an operator $\omega$ which cyclically permutes the three non-identity elements of $G$. However, no endomorphism of $A$ restricts to $\omega$.

In finite groups this is sometimes called "Does G control its own fusion in A?" and so I took a standard counterexample for that.

In abelian groups, you are more asking if $S$ is an injective module (divisible abelian group). For example, if $\omega:G\to A:n \mapsto \tfrac12 n$ where $G=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}$ are *additively-written* groups, then $\omega$ cannot be extended to $A\to A$ since then $\omega(1) = \tfrac12 \notin A$  (more formally, $\omega(1)+\omega(1) = \omega(2) = 1$, and $A$ has unique "square roots" (when thinking multiplicatively), that is, it has unique division by 2 inside $\mathbb{Q}$).

**When?** In abelian groups, you can get a nice answer for when this is possible (which $S$ work for all $G$? divisible groups, many results of Baer; which $G$ for all $S$? I think that one is direct summand, though check if pure subgroup is correct). In finite groups there are some nice sufficient conditions for control of fusion (choose $G$ abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup, for example), but I don't think the results are as clean as for abelian groups $S$, and the setup I know is a little different than your question.